# Rails 5 turbolinks don't work after installing Angular 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting an error in the following lines:

```
# layouts/application.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload' %>
```

It raises: `SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:1: reserved word 'var'`

It happened after installing Angular 2 using `$ npm install`

Comment: The error is deeper than that. Where are you using `var` in any other case than in defining a variable? You need to provide more code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed by requiring only *required* files in application.js

```
//= require node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills
//= require node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src
//= require node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx
//= require node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev
//= require_tree ./app
```